# Socket connection timout error in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rest, file-upload

I've been having trouble uploading images to cloudinary in Node JS because when I try to I get this error

```
Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout 
 {
   error: Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
       at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
       at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20)
       at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
       at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
       at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
     code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
   }
 }
```

Sometimes the image gets uploaded and sometimes it doesn't. I've looked it up online and it says poor internet connection but my internet is good enough, I've had the entire application dockerized so idk if that has something to do with it.

```
const addProduct = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const {
    title,
    snippet,
    description,
    quantity,
    price,
    coverImage,
    imageArray,
    category,
  } = req.body;
  try {
    cloudinary.api
      .ping()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(`Cloudinary connection ${res.status}`);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    const imageUrlArray: Array<imageObjectType> = [];
    const coverImageUpload = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(coverImage);
    if (imageArray !== undefined) {
      for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
        const image = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(imageArray[i]);
        imageUrlArray.push({
          publicId: image.public_id,
          secureUrl: image.secure_url,
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(req.seller);
    const product = await Product.create({
      title: title,
      snippet: snippet,
      description: description,
      quantity: quantity,
      price: price,
      coverImage: {
        publicId: coverImageUpload.public_id,
        secureUrl: coverImageUpload.secure_url,
      },
      imageArray: imageUrlArray,
      category: category,
      sellerId: req.seller,
    });
    console.log(product);
    if (product) {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Product added",
        category: category,
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

This is where I'm uploading the images and it's giving me error in the bit where I try to ping to cloudinary.

Comment: Please show the relevant upload code.  It's very hard to answer questions here without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Most likely this is an issue with your connection, or with something between your application environment and the server you're connecting to, but the error alone isn't enough to determine that - are you able to see more about the reason for the failure?

Comment: No it only says that it's a connection problem in the node errors list, but going on the official cloudinary site and uploading works at all times so idk where the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading to NodeJS 20.3.0 fixed it for me, as it seemed to have been a bug with Node 20 as pointed out by others

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue, in my case it was an bug with node 20.0.0 version. To solve it, I have to add an environment variable NODE_OPTIONS=no-network-family-autoselection

Comment: where exactly to add it

Comment: You can add it in .env file, and if it doesn't work another way is to downgrade the node version. You can try use nvm to manage the node version. I just type 'nvm use 19.9.0'.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same error on my Next.js app when uploading image to Cloudinary, using Nodejs `20.2.0`.
The only way I was able to fix is by downgrading Nodejs to LTS version.

> This bug appeared after upgrading Nodejs to latest version. It may get fixed in next updates.

Answer (score 1):

this is actually a bug with node js version
Please update node version to `v20.4.0` and everything will work fine

Answer (score 1):

there's a proxy/client request timeout bug on node version 20.2,

Use `nvm install node` to update your Node engine to the latest version.

(make sure you have nvm installed)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem my node typescript express project when uploading the file cloudinary.I tried many ways but it didn't work the ony way I solved this problem downgrading my node version 20.0.0 to 18.12.1 finally then it's work.

Answer (score 1):

We were still experiencing socket timeouts with Node 20.10.0, so whatever problem might have been solved by going to Node 20.3.x or 20.4.x does not appear to solve the whole problem.

The key for us was noticing this in the **History** section of [the socket.connect() documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v21.x/api/net.html#socketconnectoptions-connectlistener):
[image]

So in Node 20.0.0, the default value of `autoSelectFamily` in `socket.connect()` changed from `false` to `true`. We tried NODE_OPTIONS=no-network-family-autoselection as suggested by [giraffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21968380/giraffe), but it was not successful (unclear why not).  Instead, we changed our `net.createConnection()` call to set `autoDetectFamily` to `false`:

```
 const socket = net.createConnection({host, port, autoSelectFamily: false}, () => {
   // connectListener body
 });
```

and that solved the problem for us.