# Error on paginaiton from Tibia.com with Next JS API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating an aou using Next JS to get data from the Tibia game web site.

I'm having an error with the pagination, on the first page all the results are displayed correctly, from the second page onwards it no longer works. Below are my json outputs and my API code, help me fix this error.

API Code

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as cheerio from "cheerio";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { world, category, vocation, beprotection, worldtypes, page } =
    req.query;

  try {
    // https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=highscores&world=Gentebra&currentpagedisplay=2
    let url = "https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=highscores";

    // Adiciona parâmetros à URL apenas se estiverem presentes
    if (world) url += `&world=${world}`;
    if (beprotection) url += `&beprotection=${beprotection}`;
    if (category) url += `&category=${category}`;
    if (vocation) url += `&profession=${vocation}`;
    if (page) url += `&currentpage=${page}`;
    if (worldtypes) url += `&worldtypes[]=${worldtypes}`;

    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

    const highscoreList = [];
    const queryPerPage = 50;

    $(
      "table.TableContent > tbody > tr[style*='background-color:#F1E0C6'], table.TableContent > tbody > tr[style*='background-color:#D4C0A1']"
    ).each((index, element) => {
      const columns = $(element).find("td");

      const rank = columns.eq(0).text().trim();
      const name = columns.eq(1).text().trim();
      const vocation = columns.eq(2).text().trim();
      const world = columns.eq(3).text().trim();
      const level = parseInt(columns.eq(4).text().trim());
      const points = columns.eq(5).text().trim();

      const highscoreEntry = {
        rank,
        name,
        vocation,
        world,
        level,
        points,
      };

      highscoreList.push(highscoreEntry);
    });

    const totalRecords =
      highscoreList.length < queryPerPage ? highscoreList.length : 1000;
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalRecords / 50);

    // Ajuste para calcular a página atual após a iteração pelos resultados
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * queryPerPage;
    const endIndex = startIndex + queryPerPage;

    const paginatedList = highscoreList.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

    const highscorePage = {
      current_page: page,
      total_pages: totalPages,
      total_records: totalRecords,
    };

    const output = {
      highscores: {
        world,
        category,
        vocation,
        highscore_age: 20,
        highscore_list: paginatedList,
        highscore_page: highscorePage,
      },
    };

    res.status(200).json(output);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}
```

First page

```json
// 20231130114831
// http://localhost:3000/api/v1/community/highscores?world=Astera&page=1

{
  "highscores": {
    "world": "Astera",
    "highscore_age": 20,
    "highscore_list": [
      {
        "rank": "1",
        "name": "Hero Reis",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1924,
        "points": "118,392,612,632"
      },
      {
        "rank": "2",
        "name": "Angel Pro Damage",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1632,
        "points": "72,253,911,581"
      },
      {
        "rank": "3",
        "name": "The Chef",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1598,
        "points": "67,860,485,241"
      },
      {
        "rank": "4",
        "name": "Carlinnnn",
        "vocation": "Master Sorcerer",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1569,
        "points": "64,129,772,700"
      },
      {
        "rank": "5",
        "name": "The Chef Pune",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1556,
        "points": "62,556,803,339"
      },
      {
        "rank": "6",
        "name": "Eternal Ichigo Kurosaki",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1549,
        "points": "61,795,330,452"
      },
      {
        "rank": "7",
        "name": "Lady Venganza",
        "vocation": "Master Sorcerer",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1529,
        "points": "59,372,405,040"
      },
      {
        "rank": "8",
        "name": "Its Ders",
        "vocation": "Master Sorcerer",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1494,
        "points": "55,372,180,421"
      },
      {
        "rank": "9",
        "name": "Jounetsu",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1437,
        "points": "49,345,484,312"
      },
      {
        "rank": "10",
        "name": "Demon of Shadon",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1420,
        "points": "47,615,810,735"
      },
      {
        "rank": "11",
        "name": "Cebola Roxa Irritante",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1358,
        "points": "41,565,979,583"
      },
      {
        "rank": "12",
        "name": "Corztten",
        "vocation": "Master Sorcerer",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1344,
        "points": "40,314,030,067"
      },
      {
        "rank": "13",
        "name": "Drata",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1343,
        "points": "40,220,502,779"
      },
      {
        "rank": "14",
        "name": "Phroenyx",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1341,
        "points": "40,029,420,586"
      },
      {
        "rank": "15",
        "name": "Se ve rus",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1335,
        "points": "39,550,333,524"
      },
      {
        "rank": "16",
        "name": "Warriior Skeet",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1335,
        "points": "39,536,631,754"
      },
      {
        "rank": "17",
        "name": "Hawke",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1313,
        "points": "37,614,684,906"
      },
      {
        "rank": "18",
        "name": "Oozzy",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1305,
        "points": "36,902,015,111"
      },
      {
        "rank": "19",
        "name": "Nathansz",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1293,
        "points": "35,920,902,291"
      },
      {
        "rank": "20",
        "name": "Runtoxz",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1285,
        "points": "35,247,524,929"
      },
      {
        "rank": "21",
        "name": "King of Gentlemen",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1274,
        "points": "34,378,398,818"
      },
      {
        "rank": "22",
        "name": "Gugo Of Bolt",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1269,
        "points": "33,918,259,627"
      },
      {
        "rank": "23",
        "name": "Vardagszor",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1251,
        "points": "32,513,552,001"
      },
      {
        "rank": "24",
        "name": "Fanfii",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1251,
        "points": "32,480,383,830"
      },
      {
        "rank": "25",
        "name": "Esteban Tao Zia",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1249,
        "points": "32,359,931,921"
      },
      {
        "rank": "26",
        "name": "Altron Lijawyn",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1249,
        "points": "32,335,734,143"
      },
      {
        "rank": "27",
        "name": "Henan Remigio",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1249,
        "points": "32,321,444,949"
      },
      {
        "rank": "28",
        "name": "Killer Baby",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1240,
        "points": "31,699,315,082"
      },
      {
        "rank": "29",
        "name": "Lady Camile",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1236,
        "points": "31,319,671,101"
      },
      {
        "rank": "30",
        "name": "Astera boy",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1230,
        "points": "30,919,046,325"
      },
      {
        "rank": "31",
        "name": "Mariuus",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1214,
        "points": "29,732,083,052"
      },
      {
        "rank": "32",
        "name": "Galasa Wolorumus",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1194,
        "points": "28,283,688,222"
      },
      {
        "rank": "33",
        "name": "Eldrakzi",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1187,
        "points": "27,775,581,805"
      },
      {
        "rank": "34",
        "name": "Alovenus",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1179,
        "points": "27,233,492,803"
      },
      {
        "rank": "35",
        "name": "Mell",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1178,
        "points": "27,160,670,996"
      },
      {
        "rank": "36",
        "name": "Larri",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1176,
        "points": "27,012,349,177"
      },
      {
        "rank": "37",
        "name": "Slechvalk",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1168,
        "points": "26,448,719,746"
      },
      {
        "rank": "38",
        "name": "Ayy Eff Kayy",
        "vocation": "Master Sorcerer",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1165,
        "points": "26,257,155,609"
      },
      {
        "rank": "39",
        "name": "Typical Gama",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1160,
        "points": "25,933,772,003"
      },
      {
        "rank": "40",
        "name": "Lidanyl",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1159,
        "points": "25,877,545,869"
      },
      {
        "rank": "41",
        "name": "Zaolusko Nova Mente",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1159,
        "points": "25,871,044,232"
      },
      {
        "rank": "42",
        "name": "Darius Templar",
        "vocation": "Master Sorcerer",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1156,
        "points": "25,640,350,274"
      },
      {
        "rank": "43",
        "name": "Reiko Fearless",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1153,
        "points": "25,472,844,842"
      },
      {
        "rank": "44",
        "name": "Sheik Lenhador",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1153,
        "points": "25,433,438,266"
      },
      {
        "rank": "45",
        "name": "Theron guard",
        "vocation": "Royal Paladin",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1152,
        "points": "25,403,011,974"
      },
      {
        "rank": "46",
        "name": "Axy",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1152,
        "points": "25,391,449,147"
      },
      {
        "rank": "47",
        "name": "Irick Darion",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1149,
        "points": "25,172,679,715"
      },
      {
        "rank": "48",
        "name": "Freezing Hammer",
        "vocation": "Elite Knight",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1149,
        "points": "25,171,525,491"
      },
      {
        "rank": "49",
        "name": "Saokyz",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1148,
        "points": "25,094,290,553"
      },
      {
        "rank": "50",
        "name": "Ryusz",
        "vocation": "Elder Druid",
        "world": "Astera",
        "level": 1147,
        "points": "25,029,727,003"
      }
    ],
    "highscore_page": {
      "current_page": "1",
      "total_pages": 20,
      "total_records": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

from page 2

```json
// 20231130115024
// http://localhost:3000/api/v1/community/highscores?world=Astera&page=2

{
  "highscores": {
    "world": "Astera",
    "highscore_age": 20,
    "highscore_list": [
      
    ],
    "highscore_page": {
      "current_page": "2",
      "total_pages": 20,
      "total_records": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

And at first call I've received

```
AxiosError: Socket connection timeout
    at AxiosError.from (file:///C:/Users/shynz/Desktop/Apps/Web/tibia-tools-site/node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:89:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (file:///C:/Users/shynz/Desktop/Apps/Web/tibia-tools-site/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:606:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (C:\Users\shynz\Desktop\Apps\Web\tibia-tools-site\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.6.1',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=highscores&world=Astera&currentpage=1',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      protocol: 'https:',
      path: '/community/?subtopic=highscores&world=Astera&currentpage=1',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object: null prototype],
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      family: undefined,
      beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
      beforeRedirects: [Object],
      hostname: 'www.tibia.com',
      port: '',
      agent: undefined,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/community/',
      search: '?subtopic=highscores&world=Astera&currentpage=1'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /community/?subtopic=highscores&world=Astera&currentpage=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.6.1\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: www.tibia.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/community/?subtopic=highscores&world=Astera&currentpage=1',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'www.tibia.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=highscores&world=Astera&currentpage=1',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  cause: Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20)
      at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
  }
}
```

Please help me to fix this issues

Errors on getting results from Tibia Highscores while using Next JS API.

----------------------- SOLUTION -------------------------

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as cheerio from "cheerio";

const MAX_RETRIES = 3;

const fetchUrl = async (url) => {
  let retries = 0;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, { timeout: 5000 });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
      retries++;
      console.error(`Retrying (${retries}/${MAX_RETRIES})...`);
      return fetchUrl(url);
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { world, category, vocation, beprotection, worldtypes, page } =
    req.query;

  try {
    let url = "https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=highscores";
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams();

    if (world) queryParams.append("world", world);
    if (beprotection) queryParams.append("beprotection", beprotection);
    if (category) queryParams.append("category", category);
    if (vocation) queryParams.append("profession", vocation);
    if (page) queryParams.append("currentpage", page);
    if (worldtypes) queryParams.append("worldtypes[]", worldtypes);

    // Append the constructed query parameters to the URL
    url += `&${queryParams.toString()}`;

    // Fetch highscores with retry logic
    const htmlData = await fetchUrl(url);
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlData);

    const highscoreList = [];
    const queryPerPage = 50;

    $(
      "table.TableContent > tbody > tr[style*='background-color:#F1E0C6'], table.TableContent > tbody > tr[style*='background-color:#D4C0A1']"
    ).each((index, element) => {
      const columns = $(element).find("td");

      const rank = columns.eq(0).text().trim();
      const name = columns.eq(1).text().trim();
      const vocation = columns.eq(2).text().trim();
      const world = columns.eq(3).text().trim();
      const level = parseInt(columns.eq(4).text().trim());
      const points = columns.eq(5).text().trim();

      const highscoreEntry = {
        rank,
        name,
        vocation,
        world,
        level,
        points,
      };

      highscoreList.push(highscoreEntry);
    });

    const totalRecords =
      highscoreList.length < queryPerPage ? highscoreList.length : 1000;
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalRecords / 50);

    const highscorePage = {
      current_page: page,
      total_pages: totalPages,
      total_records: totalRecords,
    };

    const output = {
      highscores: {
        world,
        category,
        vocation,
        highscoreList,
        highscore_page: highscorePage,
      },
    };

    res.status(200).json(output);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure but that error might be related to this other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76179568/socket-connection-timout-error-in-node-js

Try and check if your Node version has that timeout bug other people are reporting in that question

Comment: its not the same issue :(